# Making Tumblr Widget With "MORE" Button

Tags: php, widget, blogs, tumblr

Alright, so I am trying to create a widget for my website that will display all of my recent blog posts. Tumblr already has a JS that will do this that looks like this.

```
<script src="blogname.tumblr.com/js"></script>
```

But I have recently found something better that looks like this.

```
<img border='0' style='margin:0' id='ji-tumblr-photo-blogname-1' src='' alt='' />
<script src='http://blogname.tumblr.com/api/read/json?number=10&type=photo'></script>
<script>document.getElementById('ji-tumblr-photo-blogname-1').setAttribute('src', tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['photo-url-500']);</script>
```

Not I'm not too great with JS yet but I kind of figured out that the first line and third line share the same "1", and it kind of acts as a place holder. Now in third line you will see where is says:

```
tumblr_api_read.posts[0]
```

Again, I'm not that great with JS but I've found out if you change that number it changes what post it displays from your blog. So for instance, I can take that "1" and increment it from 1-10 and increment the "0" from 0-9 and it will display my last 10 Tumblr posts. From my last post I have found out how to increment numbers with this PHP script.

```
$offset = 10;
$page = 1;

if (isset($_GET['post']) && is_numeric($_GET['post'])) {
$page = $_GET['post'];
}

$start_number = ($page - 1) * $offset;
$end_number   = $start_number + 10;

$num = $start_number;
while ($num <= $end_number) {
echo $num;
$num++;
}

echo sprintf('<a href="/index.php?page=tumblr&post=%s">More</a>', $page + 1);
```

Now I'm not really that sure "how" it works, but I know that it does work. The only problem is that it displays 0-10, and like I said I need it from 1-10 and 0-9. That way in the "while" loop where it echos out $num I can change it to.

```
<img border='0' style='margin:0' id='ji-tumblr-photo-blogname-<?php echo $onetoten; ?>' src='' alt='' />
<script src='http://blogname.tumblr.com/api/read/json?number=10&type=photo'></script>
<script>document.getElementById('ji-tumblr-photo-blogname-<?php echo $onetoten; ?>').setAttribute('src', tumblr_api_read.posts[<?php echo $zerotonine; ?>]['photo-url-500']);</script>
```

And when I press the "more" button it will increment the 0-9 to 10-19. I don't believe I have to change the "$onetoten" because it's just a place holder but for right now I'm stuck... Any help would be amazing!

Comment: it doesn't look like you've posted all of your code. but I would first check `<?php echo zerotonine; ?>` whereas you are missing the variable symbol `$` (ie `$zerotonine`)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the "$" @SamuelCook